# How to add subquery in db_select using orderBy?

Tags: views

In my project, I want do display users information(fields) by user role. I created a view for users, and I used a subquery for sorting user field by ascending order with the  following query.

```
SELECT field_level_of_work_value, FROM `field_data_field_level_of_work` ORDER BY FIELD(field_level_of_work_value, '0','1','2','3'), field_level_of_work_value ASC
```

I don't know how to use this query in `hook_view_query_alter()`. This is the code I am using.

```
function user_worklevel_sorting_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name=="attorney_workload") {
    $sub_query = db_select('node','node');
    $sub_query->addField('field_data_field_level_of_work', 'value','field_level_of_work_value');
    $sub_query->addField('users', 'uid','uid');

    $sub_query->leftJoin('field_data_field_level_of_work', 'field_data_field_level_of_work', 'field_data_field_level_of_work.entity_id=users.uid');
    $sub_query->orderBy('wl.field_level_of_work_value' , '0')
      ->orderBy('wl.field_level_of_work_value' ,'1')
      ->orderBy('wl.field_level_of_work_value' , '2')
      ->orderBy('wl.field_level_of_work_value' ,'3')
      ->orderBy('wl.field_level_of_work_value','ASC');

    $join = new views_join();
    $join->definition = array('table formula' => $sub_query, 'left_field' => 'uid', 'field' => 'uid', 'left_table' => 'node');
    $join->left_table = 'users';// or wathever table you want to join with
    $join->field = 'uid';
    $join->left_field = 'uid';// or wathever column you want to join with
    $join->type = 'LEFT';// if you want another join type play with this value

    // Do the actual join
    $query->table_queue['field_data_field_level_of_work'] = array(
      'alias' => 'field_data_field_level_of_work',// I believe this is optional
      'table' => $sub_query,
      'relationship' => 'node',
      'join' => $join,
    );
  }
}
```

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

I don't want to display null values in "Level of work" column and it would be display like my custom orderBy ASC.